# What are the Nvidia open source graphics drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nouveau, proprietary, open-source

[image: Nvidia Open Source Driver?]

I just added the Nvidia driver PPA `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`, and am noticing that a number of the options in Additional Drivers now have "(open source)" (i.e. first option in image) appended to them instead of "(proprietary)".

Sorry if I'm out of the loop, but I thought Nvidia *only* provided proprietary drivers, and it was X.Org, the makers of Nouveau, who did the open source stuff.

Can anybody clarify? Thanks!

Comment: This is a GUI bug. All drivers are proprietary.